# NoReverseMatch at / myplaylist

Tags: python, html, django, url

Error: NoReverseMatch at /myplaylists/
Reverse for 'create_playlist' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []

My urls.py:

```
url(r'^create_playlist/$', views.create_playlist, name='create_playlist'),
```

On my index page, im trying to reference that url using :

```
<a href="{% url 'create_playlist' %}">Create playlist</a>
```

Comment: Since 0 patterns were tried: are you correctly referencing this urls.py in your main urls.py?

Comment: Yup, the url, localhost:8000/create_playlist/, works perfectly!

Comment: Okay, and you are not using namespacing? If you are you need to use **url 'name_of_namespace:name_of_view'**

Comment: Thanks man! worked :)

Comment: Your welcome! I'll create an answer for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using namespacing in your application, you need to reference the namespace in your url template tag like so:

```
{% url 'name_of_namespace:name_of_view' %}
```